# how to generate all list combinations from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list such as `lis={1,2,3}` how can one generate all permutations but as list, like this (order matters)

```
{{ 1,2,3 },   (*First level can be found using Permutations[{1,2,3}]*)
 { 1,3,2 },
 { 2,1,3 },
 { 2,3,1 },
 { 3,1,2 },
 { 3,2,1 },

 { {1}, {2,3} },  (*but what about these?*)
 { {1}, {3,2} },
 { {2}, {1,3} },
 { {2}, {3,1} },
 { {3}, {1,2} },
 { {3}, {2,1} },
 { {1,2}, {3} },
 { {2,1}, {3} },
 { {1,3}, {2} },
 { {3,1}, {2} },
 { {2,3}, {1} },
 { {3,2}, {1} },

 { {1},{2},{3}},  (*last level, can be obtained from first level *)
 { {1},{3},{2}},  (*by making each element in that, as a list*)
 { {2},{1},{3}},
 { {2},{3},{1}},
 { {3},{1},{2}},
 { {3},{2},{1}},

}
```

It is similar to `Permutations` but with partition to lists as well. I looked at `Subsets`, `Partition` and number of posts, but did not see anything similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use [`Permutations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html) and [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html) with [`TakeList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList.html).

With

```
permutationsList[list_] :=
 Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Through@(
     Function[{p}, Map[TakeList[#, p] &]] /@
      Sort@Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions@Length@list, 1]
     )@Permutations[list]
```

Then

```
permutationsList@Range@3 //Column
```

> ```
> {{1,2,3}}
> {{1,3,2}}
> {{2,1,3}}
> {{2,3,1}}
> {{3,1,2}}
> {{3,2,1}}
> {{1},{2,3}}
> {{1},{3,2}}
> {{2},{1,3}}
> {{2},{3,1}}
> {{3},{1,2}}
> {{3},{2,1}}
> {{1,2},{3}}
> {{1,3},{2}}
> {{2,1},{3}}
> {{2,3},{1}}
> {{3,1},{2}}
> {{3,2},{1}}
> {{1},{2},{3}}
> {{1},{3},{2}}
> {{2},{1},{3}}
> {{2},{3},{1}}
> {{3},{1},{2}}
> {{3},{2},{1}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

There are 24 permutations to be chosen in groups of six in the original query.

`alist = {1, 2, 3}`

`s = Permutations[alist, {3}]`

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}
```

`x1 = Map[Partition[#, UpTo[1]] &, s]`

```
{{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{1}, {3}, {2}}, {{2}, {1}, {3}}, {{2}, {3}, {1}}, \
{{3}, {1}, {2}}, {{3}, {2}, {1}}}
```

`x2 = Map[Partition[#, UpTo[2]] &, s]`

```
   {{{1, 2}, {3}}, {{1, 3}, {2}}, {{2, 1}, {3}}, {{2, 3}, {1}}, {{3, 
   1}, {2}}, {{3, 2}, {1}}}
```

`x3 = Map[Partition[#, UpTo[3]] &, s]`

```
{{{1, 2, 3}}, {{1, 3, 2}}, {{2, 1, 3}}, {{2, 3, 1}}, {{3, 1, 2}}, {{3,
        2, 1}}}
```

`Join[x1, x2, x3]`

Gets the job done using the UpTo specification. x2 will need to be reversed and added to the final list.

Comment: Who is this guy?